# Are the deviations from the expectated value of a Poisson distribution normally distributed?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

If I start with a Poisson distribution $X$ and I take $n$ random samples/observations from X, with mean of the samples $= \bar{x}$, the differences between each sample observation and the mean is $(x_1-\bar{x}),...,(x_n-\bar{x})$.

These deviations from the mean should have $\mu = 0$ (obviously) and $\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n}$

How can I show that these deviations from the mean of the Poisson are themselves a normal distribution? Do I just rely on central limit theorem with ufficiently large n?

Comment: I think you meant $\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i-\bar x)=0$ instead of $\mu=0$. And $\hat \sigma^2$ (an estimator of the variance) instead of $\sigma^2$ (theoretical variance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this histogram of the deviations from the mean, from 10000 samples from a Poisson with $\lambda=2$. Is it close to Normal?

[image]

Comment: Good point, thanks. It does however look pretty close to normal for $\lambda => 10$

Comment: @amccnnll To say that it is close to normal... it must work for all lambdas. This is a counter example.